# How culturally different were the small German states within the late HRE?

Tags: germany, cultural-history, holy-roman-empire, imperial-germany, german-unification

I was reading online about the formation of the German Empire and encountered the phrases:

> At [the time the HRE came to an end] German identity only existed in a somewhat basic and symbolic form.

And also

> The common language was the foundation for a vague feeling of belonging together, [but] for the vast mass of Germans this was less important than an identity deriving from belonging to a particular region.

Considering this, I was interested in just how diverse these states were despite having been in the same 'union' under the HRE for so long. I was interested specifically in what types of cultural differences would exist between them, such as cultural values, ceremonies like holidays, differences in religious worship, art, and the like.

I tried to research this myself but all I really found was information on the political arrangement of HRE states rather than culture, and also some information on 'Germanisation' and the homogenization of German culture after the formation of the German Empire and later unified German countries. Any time the pre-unification cultural differences were brought up it was as prelude to talking about the end of separate cultures in the face of a new homogenous German culture. There wasn't so much information on what these differences actually were, which is what I'm interested in. If anyone has any info about this I'd love to hear!

Comment: It seems I overestimated how homogenous modern German culture is, but I'm still interested in the historical differences. 'Culture' is a broad idea, but it was mentioned in multiple places I was reading as having been more diverse before unifications than prior to.

Comment: Just as in Italy, each region today has its own dialect, food, ways of doing things etc. How many dialects etc. exist in England or Spain? Just because a politcal 'force' created a unified country, doesn't mean that peaple started to speak the same dialect and started doing things in the same way. This was also true during the time of the Roman Republic, where only a small portion of the population (in what is now Italy) spoke Latin (Latium is a region of Italy that contains Rome).

Comment: Dialect, food, tradition, etc was the type of info I interested in, only pointed at the later period of smaller German states. I only suggested modern German culture was 'homogenous' because it was mentioned in multiple places, but historical rather than modern Germany is what I'm interested in.

Comment: As I understand it, this is a fiendishly difficult problem. Most of the studies I've seen approach the topic in the opposite direction - how do national cultures emerge from the constitutent cultures? You may find that more useful. (e.g. how does the USA emerge from the federation of states? )  Cultural diversity is the human norm; formation of a national cultural identity is an unnatural, manufactured process.  In the case of Germany, it was the French Revolution.  In the case of Indonesia, it was the invention of a national literature, The US took a civil war.

Comment: You're probably right in how difficult the question is. I was looking at the unification of Germany when I realised I'd seen a few mentions of the differences in culture but no mention of what they actually were. I probably will follow your advice and look for studies on the unification instead and hope they mention specifics. I don't reckon anyone has specific studies like that at hand but if anyone knows of a place I could find something like that that would be very helpful :)

Comment: With the exception of the National Socialist time, there was never a great desire for a 'meltpot' society. In areas of common interest, one works togeater and respects the differences in other areas. This is true for many european countries. The European Union is built on this concept. Most peaple don't want everything to be the same no matter where one goes.

Comment: That's right; Just to confirm I'm not here asking this question because I support cultural homogenisation or anything. It was just a phrase mentioned a few times which made me wonder how different these parts of Germany used to be.

Comment: Assume that it is a misconception. Most people here prefer the notion of diversity. Before the railroads (and other forms of communications), things were definetly more diverse than now.

Comment: Some things like religion (protestant and catholic) and dialects are easy to measure and a lot of resources are readily available online. These sources will probably tell you that some German dialects can be really hard to understand for people from other parts of the country. There is regional variation in food and (I have heard) in folk music. You can easily see differences in architecture (e.g. Norddeutsche Backsteingotik) and also in the layout of villages (e.g. Angerdorf, Rundling).

Comment: Another interesting thing to look into might be how land would be inherited. Would only one child get all the land or would it be distributed equally among children? One book that touches on such topics is Hawes' The shortest history of Germany, but a) it is quite short, and b) IMHO he is overdoing the "inside the Roman Limes = cultured and democratic, outside the Roman Limes = militaristic and dictatorian" part.a bit.

Comment: Another difference might have been whether St Nicholas or the Christkind gave out presents. The Weihnachtsmann seems to not have been around yet (or not much) before the 19th century.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks very much, that's exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for, I'll be sure to look further at the stuff you mentioned

Comment: A lot of german regions had formative influences from their neighbouring countries (for example Pommerania from Sweden, Tyrolia from Italy, Lower Rhine country from the Netherlands), or were plain bi- or tri-lingual (Silesia: German, Polish and Jiddish, Bohemia/Sudeten: German and Czech, Alsatia/Lothringia/Saar: German and French). While a lot of that can be traced to shifting borders and wars, there are also the trade routes: in the north the sea trade established by the Vikings created commonalities along the Baltic sea (Hanse), in the south the Danube river connected to the Balkans.

Comment: The Kings of Denmark was dukes of the duchy of Herzogtum Oldenburg and so was subservient to the emperor in their duties as duke of Oldenburg.